# Relationship between the validity of license of an accredited CA (certificate authority and the validity of it's certificate?

Tags: authentication, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-revocation

To more clear, let's see my example:
As I know, in Korea, the validity of a CA's license is only 2 years, but the validity of this CA's certificate is 10 years.
Why is the valid time of the license short, and why is the validity time of the certificate  so long? Why 10 years, not (for example) 4,5 years?

Comment: For those of us not in Korea, can you explain who issues the licence? Is it the government?